# Intellij GWT configuration. NoSuchMethodError on module compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, gwt

I'm trying to debug my client-side code from IntelliJ.

Currently i build the project using this gradle plugin: https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin.

This is the gradle task:

```
task oneClickGwtSuperDev(type:de.richsource.gradle.plugins.gwt.GwtSuperDev){
        group = "gwt"
        workDir = file("$buildDir/gwt/work")
        noPrecompile = true
        bindAddress = '127.0.0.1'
        launcherDir = file("$projectDir/devWar")
        logLevel = 'INFO'
        port = 9876
        sourceLevel = '1.8'
    }
```

This depends on another task that starts a tomcat container, therefore i'm not using the embedded server.

My goal is to stop using the gradle task for develpment, and create a GWT configuration in intellij, in order to debug from the IDE, and not the browser.

This is what i've tried:
[image]
The codeserver starts, but when module compiles i get a NoSuchMethodError.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.GeneratedResource.setPrivate(Z)V
at org.atmosphere.gwt20.rebind.SerializerGenerator.generateIncrementally(SerializerGenerator.java:134)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:739)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:103)
```

My assumption is, when i build with the GWT configuration, the dependencies are messed up. 
The working configuration (Gradle) has some excludes in the dependencies, and i think my  problem is related to this.

```
providedCompile ('com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:' + mambu.versions.gwt) {
            exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
            exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-lang3'
            exclude group: 'commons-io', module: 'commons-io'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        }
        providedCompile('com.google.gwt:gwt-user:' + mambu.versions.gwt) {
            exclude group: 'javax.validation', module: 'validation-api'
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like incompatible Versions of `org.atmosphere.gwt20` and `com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker`

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Which Versions do you use?

Comment: You have to use a GWT-Version lower than 2.7 i guess. if you see the Javadoc, the method is deprecated in gwt-2.6 https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/javadoc/gwt-2.6.1/com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/EmittedArtifact.html#setPrivate(boolean)

Comment: Mmm ... so why does it work when i build with gradle?

Comment: I do not know. Maybe it uses an other Version of gwt or atmosphere?

Comment: versions.gwt=2.8.0
versions.jsinterop=1.0.1
versions.atmosphere=2.3.2
versions.aws=1.9.22
versions.aws.sqs.messaging=1.0.0
versions.elasticmq=0.10.0
versions.guava=21.0
versions.guice=4.0
versions.apachePoi=3.13

Comment: Change to newest atmosphere version